# Подключение asset в yii2

Tags: php, yii2

На данный момент есть главный asset приложения который подключается в главном шаблоне. Так же у меня есть модуль у которого свой asset, его я подключаю в нужных вьюхах модуля. Однако главные стили приложения перекрываю стили модуля, то есть вижу такую картинку

```
<link href="/assets/1fd9cc17/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/css/slick-theme.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/css/slick.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Возможно ли как то переопределить очередность подключения ?

Comment: нужно добавить 'ClientScript::reset()' в 'preint' метод модуля для пропуска базовых скриптов в модуле

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но можете подробнее расписать как это делать?

Answer (score 1):

В модуле должна быть папка assets, где хранятся module.css, module.js

```
class SomeModule extends CWebModule
{
    /**
     * @var string the path to this modules published asset directory
     */
    protected $assetsUrl;

    public function preinit()
    {
        // Reset the front-end's client script because we don't want
        // both front-end styles being applied in this module.
        Yii::app()->clientScript->reset();
    }

    public function init()
    {
        $this->registerCoreCss();
        $this->registerCoreJs();
    }

    /**
     * Registers the published module CSS
     */
    protected function registerCoreCss()
    {
        Yii::app()->clientScript->registerCssFile($this->getAssetsUrl('/module.css'));
    }

    /**
     * Registers the published module JS
     */
    protected function registerCoreJs()
    {
        Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScriptFile($this->getAssetsUrl('/module.js'), CClientScript::POS_BEGIN);
    }

    /**
     * Publishes and returns the URL to the assets folder.
     * @return string the URL
     */
    protected function getAssetsUrl($path = '', $home = false)
    {
        $assetsPath = ($home) ? Yii::getPathOfAlias('webroot') : Yii::getPathOfAlias('some.assets');
        $assetsUrl  = Yii::app()->assetManager->publish($assetsPath . $path, false, -1, false);

        return $assetsUrl;
    }

}
```